Define multiple GNU Makefile variables from $(shell...)
I have a file (e.g. iostruct.def) with some variable definitions in it:
VARIABLE_A=/some/path
VARIABLE_B=/another/path
...

I want to read this file from a GNU Makefile, prefix all paths by some string (e.g. /tmp) and use them as normal Make variables.
Here is my (failed) attempt on this:
vars := $(shell sed -r "s|=(\/.*)|=/tmp\1|" iostruct.def)
$(eval $(foreach v,$(vars),$(v)))
all:
    @echo $(VARIABLE_A)
    @echo $(VARIABLE_B)

However I end up with VARIABLE_A="/tmp/some/path VARIABLE_B=/tmp/another/path" and VARIABLE_B is empty. What am I doing wrong?
PS. The emphasis is on the on-the-fly definition of multiple Make variables coming from $(shell ...); the tmp prefixing of values is just an example.

You can't do it this way because the result of the $(shell ...) function will be a string with all newlines converted into spaces, just like backticks in the shell.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html  So all newlines are lost and the result is a single string.

Actually the $(foreach), takes a space delimitted list, which is what OP wants -- the issue comes in that the $(foreach ...) outputs a single line, so only one line is evaluated.

One easy to understand solution is to convert the iostruct.def file using shell commands into the format you want, then include that file.  Like this:
all:
        @echo $(VARIABLE_A)
        @echo $(VARIABLE_B)

include iostruct.def.mk

iostruct.def.mk: iostruct.def
        sed -r 's|=(\/.*)|=/tmp\1|' $< > $@

For more details see Remaking Makefiles in the GNU Make manual.

The issue you're encountering is that your foreach loop only outputs a single line.  So it would basically expand to:
$(eval VARIABLE_A=/tmp/some/path VARIABLE_B=/tmp/another/path)

You can resolve this two ways:  First, you can eval each $(v) separately:
$(foreach v,$(vars),$(eval $(v)))

or you can create a multiline output:
#end of line: note -- you must have two newlines here...
define eol


endef

$(eval $(foreach v,$(vars),$(v)$(eol)))

A side note: you can replace $(eval...) with $(info ...) to see what's being evaluated.

Note that the above will break if any of your variables have spaces, or you put spaces around = signs, as this will confuse the foreach (which takes a space delimitted list).   If this is a possibility, use @MadScientists answer where you generate a makefile
